# How to handle image creation, search and deletion properly?

Tags: python, image

Tides are changing and so is the Blender Python API. I would like to know **how to properly create, search for and delete an image** as my own experiments show confusing results.

At the moment, I have troubles finishing my script for spritesheet generation. It renders animation frames, saves them, loads to actually have access to the pixels, inserts those pixels into a new pool of pixels which will finally be assigned as pixels of the spritesheet. This works fabulously, however, **I have problems creating the spritesheet image from scratch while only maintaining one image of that name** (older ones might exist from previous script runs for example).

In my version of Blender (2.72) **`bpy.ops.image.new` does not return the image object but a rather useless finilization-message**. This means, **I have have to grab the image from `bpy.data.images` by name** if I don't want iterate over all of them to check for more matching attributes beside the name. There is the catch: **Blender automatically iterated the name of already existing image names** and seemingly does this differently from time to time. How am I suposed to know exactly the way, the automatic names are numbered? And even if I know that, why must I iterate over all images with a similar name until I identify the one with the highes number behind it? This seems inpractical.

Ok, what if I **check if an image of that name already exists and delete it** accordingly? This mus free the desired name, though it bears some risks in complex working environments. I will have to clear its users as well as delete it completely to get it out off the system for good. And this is what I tried to do in my spritesheet generator (code snippet):

```
if spriteSheetName in bpy.data.images:
    # delete previous spritesheet radically
    spriteSheet = bpy.data.images[spriteSheetName]
    if spriteSheet != None:
        spriteSheet.user_clear()
        bpy.data.images.remove(spriteSheet)
# create new one
bpy.ops.image.new(name = spriteSheetName, 
    width = shPxWidth, height = shPxHeight, 
    color = [1, 1, 1, 0], alpha = True)
spriteSheet = bpy.data.images[spriteSheetName]
spriteSheet.filepath = imgDirectory + "\\" + spriteSheetName + "." + imgType
spriteSheet.file_format = imgType.upper()
```

This results in errors taking place in the Blender Python Api itself:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\Programs\Blender Foundation\blender-2.72b-windows64\2.72\scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_image.py", line 414, in draw
    MASK_MT_editor_menus.draw_collapsible(context, layout)
  File "B:\Programs\Blender Foundation\blender-2.72b-windows64\2.72\scripts\modules\bpy_types.py", line 770, in draw_collapsible
    cls.draw_menus(layout, context)
  File "B:\Programs\Blender Foundation\blender-2.72b-windows64\2.72\scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_image.py", line 497, in draw_menus
    if ima and ima.is_dirty:
AttributeError: 'ID' object has no attribute 'is_dirty'

location: <unknown location>:-1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\Programs\Blender Foundation\blender-2.72b-windows64\2.72\scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_image.py", line 414, in draw
    MASK_MT_editor_menus.draw_collapsible(context, layout)
  File "B:\Programs\Blender Foundation\blender-2.72b-windows64\2.72\scripts\modules\bpy_types.py", line 770, in draw_collapsible
    cls.draw_menus(layout, context)
  File "B:\Programs\Blender Foundation\blender-2.72b-windows64\2.72\scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_image.py", line 497, in draw_menus
    if ima and ima.is_dirty:
AttributeError: 'ID' object has no attribute 'is_dirty'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

So, I am asking you if you know proper image handling via the Blender Python API.

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This:     `bpy.data.images.new(name, width, height, alpha=False, float_buffer=False, stereo3d=False)` returns the image created.

`bpy.data.images.remove(image)` removes the image.

Comment: ``bpy.data.images.new`` is what I sought after. It's easy to release the users and remove the image, now. Frankly, some unexpected bugs (?) in my surrounding scripts occured, but - hey - human error knows no limits!

When in comes to naming

Comment: Cool, so this can be marked as answered?

Comment: Not yet. Maybe someone has more to add. If it's like in stackoverflow, I would have to wait 2 days anyway to give anybody the final answered mark.